# Import function from another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

This is my project structure :

```
- dir1/
    - __init__.py
    - helper.py
    - dir1.py
    
- dir2/
    - __init__.py
    - dir2Functions.py
    - dir2main.py
```

Inside helper.py, I'm trying to import dir2Functions as following :

```
from dir2.dir2Functions import functionxx
```

I got this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir2'` 
Any suggestions to solve the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using these lines:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(sys.argv[0]).resolve().parent.parent))
```

Comment: Modifying the path from the script works, yes, but that is really not the recommended way to do it... The path should be configured "from the outside".

Answer (score 0):

You can import the function relatively:

```
from ..dir2.dir2Functions import functionxx
```

Read the documentation about [Package Relative Imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).

Comment: It didn't solve the issue

Comment: Make sure that you create an actual package and run the script from a parent directory. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/4151233

Answer (score 0):

If you have this directory structure:

```
- /path/to/base/dir/
    - dir1/
        - __init__.py
        - helper.py
        - dir1.py
    - dir2/
        - __init__.py
        - dir2Functions.py
        - dir2main.py
```

and you want to run `helper.py`, then the correct way to run it is:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/base/dir python -m dir1.helper
```

The point is that Python is going to look for packages and modules within the python path. By default, the directory in which the main script is located is added to the path, but if that is not the root of your source tree, then you need to specify the path manually.

Alternatively, you can put the main script in the root directory and run it directly, i.e.:

```
- /path/to/base/dir/
    - main.py
    - dir1/
        - __init__.py
        - helper.py
        - dir1.py
    - dir2/
        - __init__.py
        - dir2Functions.py
        - dir2main.py
```

and then from `/path/to/base/dir/`, simply run `python main.py`.